# page viewer auto incrementing on swipe

Tags: android-fragments, swipe-gesture, android-pageradapter

I have videos link in an array, and I am using a vertical page viewer and Fragment instance to swipe between videos vertically. The first and the last fragments are working fine, but when I swipe or click on the first video that is index 0 of videos array, then the video of index 1 is playing and pausing, but the action is not happening for index 0. Please help me with a solution, I have been trying for past 2 days, and I am new to android studio.

```
package com.example.final_view_pager;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.VideoView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.PagerAdapter;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

MyAdapter mAdapter;
VerticalViewPager mPager;
public static VideoView videoView;

private String videosArray[] = {
        "android.resource://com.example.final_view_pager/" + R.raw.four,
        "android.resource://com.example.final_view_pager/" + R.raw.six,
        "android.resource://com.example.final_view_pager/" + R.raw.video,
        "android.resource://com.example.final_view_pager/" + R.raw.video1,
        "android.resource://com.example.final_view_pager/" + R.raw.video2,
        "android.resource://com.example.final_view_pager/" + R.raw.video3,
        "android.resource://com.example.final_view_pager/" + R.raw.video5,
        "android.resource://com.example.final_view_pager/" + R.raw.video6
};


@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mAdapter = new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), videosArray);
    mPager = findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    mPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {


            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " current position is " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //Log.i("page", "on page scrolled");
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            Integer current_item = mPager.getCurrentItem();
            Log.i("page", " cure pos " + current_item);

            FragmentInstance.newInstance(position, videosArray[position]);
            Log.i("page", "on page selected position is " + position);
        }


        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
            //Log.i("page", "on page scroll state changed");
        }
    });
}

public static class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    String videosArray[];
    //private long baseId = 0;

    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm, String[] videosArr) {
        super(fm);
        videosArray = videosArr;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return videosArray.length;
        //return 3;
        //return NUMBER_OF_PAGES;
    }


    public void notifyChangeInPosition(int n) {
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(View collection, int position, Object view) {
        ((ViewPager) collection).removeView((View) view);
    }


    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    }

}

public static class FragmentInstance extends Fragment {

    private static final String videourlname = "video_url";
    private static final String indexs = "position";
    String videourl;
    Integer position;

    static FragmentInstance newInstance(Integer position, String videourl) {
        FragmentInstance f = new FragmentInstance();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(videourlname, videourl);
        args.putInt(indexs, position);
        f.setArguments(args);
        return f;
    }


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);

        videoView = v.findViewById(R.id.video_view);
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(videourl);
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "url is " + videourl, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

        videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
        Log.i("page", "playing position is " + position);
        if (position == 1) {
            Log.i("page", "position is different" + position);
            videoView.start();
        }

        videoView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.i("page", "clicked position is " + position);
                if (videoView.isPlaying()) {
                    Log.i("page", "playing check position  is" + position);
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), " clicked position is " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    videoView.pause();
                } else {
                    Log.i("page", "playing else  position  is" + position);
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), " clicked position is " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    videoView.start();
                }
            }
        });
        return v;
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        videourl = getArguments() != null ? getArguments().getString(videourlname) : "Null";
        position = getArguments() != null ? getArguments().getInt(indexs) : 0;

    }


}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit, could you please help me with a solution.

Comment: Does anyone have solution for this query?